# CCSprite won't add itself to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add an `CCSprite`to an array so I can do stuff with in another method. The array is just simply declared in the `@interface` like this `NSMutableArray *currentBombs;`
. I then try to add the `(CCSprite*)sprite`to the array with `[currentBombs addObject:sprite];`

The problem is that when I log `[currentBombs count]` or try to use any objects in it or log it or whatever, its empty. As CCSprite is a subclass of NSObject I would think that you can add it to an array? What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: More detailed code:

```
-(void)aMethod:(CCSprite*)Sprite{
//...
    currentBombs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [currentBombs addObject:sprite];
}
```

Then I access it a second after in the method

```
-(void)checkDamageForBomb{
currentBombs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
int cB = [currentBombs count];

for (int q = 0; q <= cB;q++)
{   
    CCSprite *bomb = [currentBombs objectAtIndex:q];//Crashes
    CGPoint bombPos = [self tileCoordForPosition:bomb.position];//Crashes 

//........ }
```

Comment: did you alloc init currentBombs?

Comment: make sure you say `currentBombs = [NSMutableArray array]` and then try adding it and then log it immediately after. It may not be initialized or it may be being reinitialized before you log it.

Comment: @savner Wow, I really managed to forget that. hahaha. It crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 1 now though so that really get me anywhere

Comment: Post the full code so we can find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because every time that you call checkDamageForBomb: you reallocate the array. You should instantiate the object just once.

My suggest is to use a property with lazy initialization, and always call *self.currentBombs*:

```
@interface MyClass()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray* currentBombs;

@end

@implementation MyClass

#pragma mark - Accessors

- (NSMutableArray*) currentBombs
{
    if(!_currentBombs)
        _currentBombs=[NSMutableArray array];
    return _currentBombs;
}
```

This way you have to change your code and always call *self.currentBombs*:

```
-(void)checkDamageForBomb{

    for(CCSprite* bomb in self.currentBombs)  // I find fast enumeration more elegant.
    {
        CGPoint bombPos = [self tileCoordForPosition:bomb.position];
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So that you don't care of allocating it, the accessor will do it for you the first time that you call it.

Comment: I don't understand the `for(Bomb* bomb in self.currentBombs)` part. How do I create the "Bomb*" object? It just errors me.

Comment: Well it was a *CCSprite*, fixed it. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the variable currentBombs twice.  Initialize it once in e.g. ViewDidLoad